# Find smallest 2 consecutive cells in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to find the smallest 2 consecutive cells in Google Spreadsheets?  So for A1:A5, it would sum A1:A2, A2:A3, A3:A4, and A4:A5, and then return the smallest of those numbers.  I am using MIN for other uses, but I don't see an option to do this specific request using MIN.

Answer (score 2):

```
=MIN(ArrayFormula(A1:A4 + A2:A5))
```